# AngularJS: Is there any way to get size of file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filereader

I'm implementing a check in which I dont want to upload the image which has size greater than `4MB`. I'm using `file reader` and `new image()`. I've the image size and width. But how can I get the filesize.

```
function previewImage(element) {
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function (event) {
    seAddArtist.imageSource = event.target.result;
    $scope.$apply();
  };
  // when the file is read it triggers the onload event above.
  reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
}


var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
  alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
}
```

I am implementing these two combine but how can i check the size of image?

Comment: Better check during selecting file(s). JS has the API. Reading for checking size is not a good way to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`FileReader` ([FileReader API](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filereader)) itself does not provide the size of an file. You need to use `file` ([file API](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-file)) instead:

```
function previewImage(element) {
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(event) {
    seAddArtist.imageSource = event.target.result;
    $scope.$apply();
  };

  // when the file is read it triggers the onload event above.
  reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);

  //log / access file size in bytes
  console.log(element.files[0].size + ' Bytes');

  //log / access file size in Mb
  console.log(element.files[0].size/1024/1024 + ' MB');

  if (element.files[0].size/1024/1024 > 4) {
   console.log('file is bigger than 4MB);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That might be what you want:

```
var size = files[0].size;
```

Comment: we are using .size but it is not giving accurate result, my file is of size 976567kb(97mb) but it shows 100000(100mb). Do you have any idea why it is wrong value?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the file size before submitting:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function checkFileSize() {
        var size = document.getElementById("fileSelector").files[0].size;
        alert("file size: " + size);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="fileSelector" type="file" onchange="checkFileSize()"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working code to get file size. you will get file size in KB.

```
<input id="file" type="file">
<img id="filerendered" src="">
```

and in script tag

```
document.getElementById('file').onchange = function (event) {
var targetn = event.target || window.event.srcElement,
    files = targetn.files;

// FileReader here
if (FileReader && files && files.length) {
    var thisReader = new FileReader();

    alert("your file size "+ (files[0].size)/1024 + "kb")

    thisReader.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("filerendered").src = thisReader.result;
    }
    thisReader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
}

// for Not supported case
else {
    // not supported
}
}
```